# Not able to update picklist fields as unrestricted from restricted

Tags: apex, picklist, fields, global-picklist

[image]

The option “ Restricted picklist to the values defined in the value set “ greyed out. I need to unrestricted this field.
I am not sure why it is greyed out?
How can I unrestricted this field now?

Comment: Just a note that I greatly prefer restricted picklists as it protects you from having junk values entered by code or integration.  You can use record types on the object to control which picklist values are visible from a global value set, if that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot uncheck the restriction if the picklist is using a Global value set.  A global picklist is a restricted picklist by nature. Only a Salesforce admin can add to or modify its values. You would need to create a new field in order to remove the custom field's connection to a Global value set.

Check more details [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.fields_creating_global_picklists.htm&type=5) and also You might want to check [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E665QAC) link and vote for this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using Global Value Set here.
You can recreate this picklist with exact same values like in value set for example.